# How to install zenmap on Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, nmap, port-scanning

I'm trying to install Zenmap after installing Nmap however it's not quite working. I tried just the regular terminal command dnf install zenmap however it tells me that they're unable to find a match.

I then went to the official website to download the RPM file and tried using the command 'rpm -i filename.rpm' which told me I needed to download PyGTK which I did and it worked. However, now when I try to run zenmap, it shows me

File "/usr/bin/zenmap", line 182
except ImportError, e:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When I try launching zenmap from the search, it shows Zenmap GUI port Scanner but when I try clicking on it, there's a brief flash on my screen and then it's gone. I tried looking for solutions but there's only 2 when I search and neither of them has an answer to it.

I'm using Fedora 31 with KDE Plasma.

Comment: A valid question, but you have posted to the wrong site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585002/190343) help ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the python version in the system. zenmap fails with python3, try using python2.7 instead of python3.